# error:Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sharekit

I am new to iPhone development and I am implementing a new facebook sharing. After adding sharekit folder it's giving the following error when it runs:

`ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJSON in /Users/anil/Desktop/untitled folder 2/SMSCollection_15-10-mng/DerivedData/elsner_frmwrk/Build/Intermediates/elsner_frmwrk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/elsner_frmwrk.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJSON-48FA8505A9CE4B54.o and /Users/anil/Desktop/untitled folder 2/SMSCollection_15-10-mng/DerivedData/elsner_frmwrk/Build/Intermediates/elsner_frmwrk.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/elsner_frmwrk.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJSON-D2068CA62086265C.o for architecture i386`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using two different versions of an SBJSON framework.

Comment: Yes, apparently that was a cake walk ;)